# Number.subtract: Parameter 'left' is required in a for loop

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have generated 86 grids covering the study area. I want to count NDVI information on multiple elevation gradients (eg 1300-1500, 1500-1700, etc.) within each grid. I already have a collection of NDVI images and the collection of elevation gradients for the entire study area.

First, I use a for-loop for each grid. In this loop, I crop the collections of NDVI and elevation gradients for the entire study area, according to the grid, calculating an average NDVI over each elevation gradient (the slope of change). However, **"Number.subtract: Parameter 'left' is required."**

I'm guessing it's because some grids may not have corresponding elevation gradients. How could I fix that?

Here is the link to my code https://code.earthengine.google.com/f4c152af7ef79e45f7c72dad27c1e845.

```
//基于研究区生成50公里网格
var table_toGem = ee.FeatureCollection(table).geometry()
var grid = ee.Geometry(table_toGem).coveringGrid({
  proj:'EPSG:4326', 
  scale:50000
})

//为每个网格添加‘id’属性，用于之后逐网格统计,id从左下至右上逐渐增大
var size=grid.size()
var toList = grid.toList(size)
var idList = ee.List.sequence(0, size.subtract(1))
var newList = idList.map(function(x){
  var index = idList.get(x)
  var feat = toList.get(x)
  return ee.Feature(feat).set('id', index).copyProperties(feat).geometry()
})
/*
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection:newList,
  fileFormat:'SHP' 
})*/
var IC = ee.ImageCollection(imageCollection).map(function (img) {return img.updateMask(mask_w)}).sort('system:time_start')
var dataset = ee.Image('USGS/SRTMGL1_003').clip(table);
var elevation = dataset.select('elevation');
var ele_lis = ee.List.sequence(1300,4500,200)//依据最低和最高海拔，以200米为海拔梯度
var ele_lis_grad = ee.List.sequence(0,15,1).map(function(i) {//共17个元素，最后一个梯度的左边界不能是4500，所以i只有16个取值
  var ele_lis0 =ee.Number(ele_lis.get(i))
  var ele_lis1 =ee.Number(ele_lis0).add(200)
  var elevation0 =elevation.updateMask(elevation.gte(ele_lis0).and(elevation.lt(ele_lis1))) 
  var aspect = ee.Terrain.aspect(elevation0);
  var N_aspect =aspect.updateMask(aspect.gt(0).and(aspect.lte(45).or(aspect.gt(315).and(aspect.lte(360)))))
  var S_aspect =aspect.updateMask(aspect.gt(135).and(aspect.lte(225)))
   return N_aspect.rename('N_aspect').addBands(S_aspect.rename('S_aspect'))
})
   ele_lis_grad = ee.ImageCollection(ele_lis_grad).filter(ee.Filter.eq('isNull', false))
print(ele_lis_grad)
//创建一个包含年份的列表以作为拟合的自变量
var Time = ee.List.sequence(1986,2020,1).remove(1999)
var ele_lis_grad_L =ee.List([])
//逐网格循环
for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {                  //共有86个网格
var grid0 = newList.get(i);
var IC_NDVI_aspect0 = IC.filterBounds(grid0).toList(34);
var ele_lis_grad_li = ee.ImageCollection(ele_lis_grad).filterBounds(grid0).filter(ee.Filter.eq('isNull', false)).sort('system:time_start').toList(16)
print(ele_lis_grad_li)
var ele_lis_grad_l = ee.List.sequence(0,15,1).map(function(i){
  var ele_lis_grad_l0 = ee.Image(ele_lis_grad_li.get(i))
  var IC_NDVI_aspect_l0 = ee.List.sequence(0,33,1).map(function(a){ //替代for循环 可以将影像集转为列表，并创建一个包含索引的新列表进行map
  var img = ee.Image(IC_NDVI_aspect0.get(a));
  var IC_NDVI_aspect_S0 = img.updateMask(ele_lis_grad_l0.select('S_aspect')).reduceRegion({
      reducer:ee.Reducer.mean(),
      geometry: grid0,
      scale: 30,
      maxPixels: 1e13,
  }).get('ndvi');
  var IC_NDVI_aspect_N0 = img.updateMask(ele_lis_grad_l0.select('N_aspect')).reduceRegion({
      reducer:ee.Reducer.mean(),
      geometry: grid0,
      scale: 30,
      maxPixels: 1e13,
  }).get('ndvi');

var Diff_N_S0 =ee.Number(IC_NDVI_aspect_N0).subtract(ee.Number(IC_NDVI_aspect_S0)).divide(10000)  
return Diff_N_S0
})
//将自变量和因变量构建为列表
var feC = Time.zip(IC_NDVI_aspect_l0)
//线性拟合 自变量是时间，因变量是南北坡差值
var Diff_linearFit = feC.reduce(ee.Reducer.linearFit())

return Diff_linearFit
})
ele_lis_grad_L =ele_lis_grad_L.add(ele_lis_grad_l)
}
print(ele_lis_grad_L)
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Coding questions here are expected to contain code. Please [Edit] the Question to contain a code snippet that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Following link is your code without for-loop (it is easier to debug it): https://code.earthengine.google.com/3d6779f319cb5d6f0179c8490899b292 . However, you need to start over again.  Your error message is due to a lot of missing parameters or wrong calculated. Aspect images are completely masked and NDVI images have weird values (divided by 10,000 they would be acceptable).